# Is there a generic version of the HybridDictionary?

Tags: .net

The description of System.Collection.Specialized.HybridDictionary is this:

> Implements IDictionary by using a
>   System.Collections.Specialized.ListDictionary
>   while the collection is small, and
>   then switching to a
>   System.Collections.Hashtable when the
>   collection gets large.

Is there an equivalent Generic implementation?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not that I know of. However, is there a proven need? Hash tables don't have a large overhead, even for very small *N* it should be faster just to use the normal hash table than to search linearly.

**EDIT** I don't have a benchmark to prove it but just by comparing the algorithms I conclude that hash tables should be faster than linear search as soon as *N* > 6 on average (for string keys or similar nontrivial hashes) so there is really no reason for a hybrid implementation.

The argument is as follows. In linear search, on average half the elements have to be compared to your input, i.e. *N* / 2. In a hash table, it is known that the expected number of comparisons is 2, regardless of input size (for very small hash tables with a load factor of less than 0.1 this is actually approaching 1). Additionally, the hash has to be calculated. This results in 3 operations on your input, plus a very small overhead that can be neglected. Thus, we search for which *N* it is true that 3 > *N* / 2, which is trivially *N* > 6.

Note that the above calculation is actually wrong because for this small number of elements, the load factor of .NET's `Dictionary` will be much less than 0.1. The tipping point is therefore actually even lower.

Comment: This assumes no CPU optimizations can be made for the linear search case.  For an array, the items are stored sequentially in memory and the CPU can prefetch the data into the CPU's cache.  For the hashetable case, it has to first compute the hash and then wait for the memory fetch of the result.  In the first case, your bottleneck is the speed at which your CPU can iterate through items in its cache.  In the second case your bottleneck (for small collections) is time spent waiting for the memory fetch which can't be done in opportunistically in advance.