# VB dictionary of Objects ByRef

Tags: vb.net, com, dictionary, byref

I want to create a `Dim Dict As New Dictionary(Of String, Object)` which would point my strings to specific COM Object classes, i.e. `Dict.Add("NODES",Visum.Net.Nodes)`
I'd have around 20 keys in dictionary, each pointing to a different class within COM object.

Basically it works, but I'm afraid it's very heavy (dict of 20 instances of big classes) and not neccessary - I'm passing whole object to a dict, while I really need just kind of pointer (`ByRef`).

Is there a more clever way to do it?

PS. Why I do it? Because all objects which I'd put inside the dictionary have common methods. This way I'd be able to call i.e. : `Dict("Nodes").ItemByKey(13)`, and then `Dict("Links").ItemByKey(13)`, etc.

Thanks in advance
Rafal

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are under a misconception.  You are **already** passing, and storing, a reference to your objects.  That is the way VB.NET works.  (It is also the VB6 dealt with objects, if that is your background).  `ByVal` vs `ByRef` parameters with object types doesn't create copies of your objects, it just indicates if the method you called could, effectively, swap out your passed object with another.

Comment: so is my solution effective, or not?

Comment: I didn't understand one bit of your "PS Why..." section, but if your question was about how to store references to COM objects in a dictionary that is keyed by string, then your code does indeed accomplish this.

Comment: thank's - basically that's what I needed: to know is creating a dictionary duplicates objects.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at HybridDictionary: From MSDN: Implements IDictionary by using a ListDictionary while the collection is small, and then switching to a Hashtable when the collection gets large.

However, there is no readily-available generic version: [Is there a generic version of the HybridDictionary?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/386823/is-there-a-generic-version-of-the-hybriddictionary)

Comment: but my point is not to create a light and fast dictionary, but to pass proper type inside.