# Can I add Integer Items to VBA Dictionary byRef

Tags: vba, dictionary, outlook

Creating a dictionary in VBA and I came across something that I found curious.

When I add an Outlook Calendar Item object to a dictionary it is `ByRef`, but when I add a dimmed Integer it is `ByVal`.

My two questions are:

1. Is it possible to add the dimmed Integer `ByRef`?
2. Why are these two items added differently (I know that one is an object and one is base type, looking for a little more detail)?

I looked at this: [VB dictionary of Objects ByRef](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15523950/vb-dictionary-of-objects-byref), but it only talks about the object case and not the integer case.

Here is the code showing what happens:

```
Sub checkbyref()

    Dim gCal As Items
    Dim dict As New Scripting.Dictionary
    Set dict = New Scripting.Dictionary
    Dim intCheck As Integer

    intCheck = 5
    Set gCal = GetFolderPath("\\GoogleSync\GoogleSyncCal").Items 'gets caledar items based on path

    strMeetingStart = "01/5/2019 12:00 AM"
    strGSearch = "[Start] >= '" & strMeetingStart & "'"

    gCal.Sort "[Start]"
    Set gCal = gCal.Restrict(strGSearch)

    Debug.Print intCheck 'prints "5"
    Debug.Print gCal(1).Start 'prints 1/7/2019 9:30:00 AM"

    dict.Add "check", intCheck
    dict.Add "cal", gCal(1)

    'direction 1
    dict("check") = 4
    dict("cal").Start = "1/1/2020 9:00 AM"
    Debug.Print intCheck 'prints "5"
    Debug.Print gCal(1).Start 'prints "1/1/2020 9:00:00 AM"


    'direction 2
    intCheck = 6
    gCal(1).Start = "1/1/2021 9:00 AM"
    Debug.Print dict("check") 'prints "4"
    Debug.Print dict("cal").Start 'prints "1/1/2021 9:00:00 AM"

End Sub
```

As you can see intCheck is not effected by changes in the dict but gCal(1) is.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**tldr;** No, you can't add an intrinsic type to a `Scripting.Dictionary` `ByRef`. VBA is not the same type of managed environment as .NET (which uses generational garbage collection instead of reference counting), so proper memory management would be impossible. Note that .NET `Dictionary`'s don't work that way with intrinsic types either.

---

For the second part of your question, the thing to keep in mind is that `Dictionary` is a COM object - when you reference it in a project (or call `CreateObject` on one of its types), it starts up a COM server for scrrun.dll to provide `Scripting` objects to the caller. That means that when you make *any* call on one of its members, you're passing all of the arguments through the COM marshaller. The `Add` method is a member of the `IDictionary` interface, and has this interface description:

```
[id(0x00000001), helpstring("Add a new key and item to the dictionary."), helpcontext(0x00214b3c)]
HRESULT Add(
                [in] VARIANT* Key, 
                [in] VARIANT* Item);
```

Note that both the `Key` and `Item` are pointers to a `Variant`. When you pass an `Integer` (or any other intrinsic type), the run-time is first performing a cast to a `Variant`, then passing the resulting `Variant` pointer to the `Add` method. At this point, the `Dictionary` is solely responsible for managing the memory of the copy. A [`VARIANT`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/oaidl/ns-oaidl-tagvariant) with an intrinsic type contains the *value* of the intrinsic in its data area - not a pointer to the underlying memory.  This means that when the marshaller casts it, the only thing that ends up getting passed is the value. Contrast this to an `Object`.  An `Object` wrapped in a `Variant` has the pointer to its `IDispatch` interface in the data area, and the marshaller has to increment the reference count when it wraps it.

---

The inherent issue in passing intrinsic types as pointers is that there is no way for the either side of the COM transaction to know who is responsible for freeing the memory when it goes out of scope. Consider this code:

```
Dim foo As Scripting.Dictionary  'Module level

Public Sub Bar()
    Dim intrinsic As Integer

    Set foo = New Scripting.Dictionary
    foo.Add "key", intrinsic
End Sub
```

The problem is that `intrinsic` is allocated memory on the stack when you execute `Bar`, but `foo` isn't freed when the procedure exits - `intrinsic` is.  If the run-time passed `intrinsic` as a reference, you would be left with a bad pointer stored in `foo` after that memory was deallocated.  If you tried to use it later in another procedure, you would either get a trash value if the memory was re-used, or an access violation.

---

Now compare this to passing an `Object`:

```
Dim foo As Scripting.Dictionary  'Module level

Public Sub Bar()
    Dim obj As SomeClass

    Set foo = New Scripting.Dictionary
    Set obj = New SomeClass
    foo.Add "key", obj
End Sub
```

Objects in VBA are reference counted, and the reference count determines their life-span.  The run-time will only release them when the reference count is zero.  In this case, when you `Set obj = New SomeClass`, it increments the reference count to one. `obj` (the local variable) holds a pointer to that created object. When you call `foo.Add "key", obj`, the marshaller wraps the object in a `Variant` and increments the reference count again to account for its pointer to the object. When the procedure exits, `obj` loses scope and the reference count is decrement, leaving a count of 1. The run-time knows that something has a pointer to it, so it doesn't tear down the object because there is a possibility that it will be accessed later. It won't decrement the reference count again until `foo` is destroyed and the last reference to the object is decremented.

---

As to your first question, the only way to do something like this in VBA would be to provide your own object wrapper to "box" the value:

```
'BoxedInteger.cls
Option Explicit

Private boxed As Integer

Public Property Get Value() As Integer
    Value = boxed
End Property

Public Property Let Value(rhs As Integer)
    boxed = rhs
End Property
```

If you wanted to get fancy with it, you could make `Value` [the default member](http://www.cpearson.com/excel/DefaultMember.aspx). Then your code would look something more like this:

```
Dim dict As New Scripting.Dictionary
Set dict = New Scripting.Dictionary
Dim check As BoxedInteger

Set check = New BoxedInteger
check.Value = 5

dict.Add "check", check
```

Comment: Thank you for the very thorough explanation as well as the wrapper based workaround. I will admit that I had to do a little reading as this answer was initially outside of the scope of my knowledge - which is exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: I actually never knew about the ability to assign Attribute (default) to VBA classes. Given this though. had you actually made Value the default, then you could assign just like an Integer [ check = 5 ].

Answer (score 3):

Add method of dictionary just adds a key and item pair to a Dictionary object. In case of `dict.Add "check", intCheck` the item here is an integer value. which means there is no reference added, just the integer value. If you want to track the original variable back, you will need to wrapp it in a class as the user Comintern has suggested, or you will have to update both, the dictionary and the original integer variable, simultaneously. Example:

```
Sub checkbyref()
    Dim dict As New Scripting.Dictionary
    Set dict = New Scripting.Dictionary
    Dim intCheck As Integer

    intCheck = 5
    Debug.Print intCheck 'prints "5"
    dict.Add "check", intCheck

    ' dict("check") = 4
    SetDictionaryWithInteger dict, "check", 4, intCheck
    Debug.Print dict("check") & "|" & intCheck

    ' intCheck = 6
    SetDictionaryWithInteger dict, "check", 6, intCheck
    Debug.Print dict("check") & "|" & intCheck

End Sub

Private Sub SetDictionaryWithInteger( _
    dic As Scripting.Dictionary, _
    key As String, _
    newVal As Integer, _
    ByRef source As Integer)
    dic(key) = newVal
    source = newVal
End Sub
```

Note: `ByRef` is the [default](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/sub-statement) in Visual Basic, here it is used only to emphasize that the integer value of `intCheck` will be modified.

And to answer your questions:
1. no, integer is added like a value
2. they are not added differently, they are both added the same, which means its values is added. But in case of `intCheck` it is the value itself (e.g. 5) and nothing more, but in case of `gCal` the value is the address to the data structure, so it can be still reached through this address.

Comment: Thanks. Simple explanation was helpful before diving deeper with @Comintern 's answer.  Interesting workaround - probably where I would have gone on my own to deal with the problem.